# Angular ng-model combobox with other option and a textbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a combobox with `ng-model='languale'`. I also have a predefined list let say `'English', 'French', 'German' and 'Other'`

If I select `Other` option then another textbox need to be appeared. I have achived this functionality with `ng-show`.

Now my problem is in my JSON structure there is only one filed for language as follows

```
var peopleData = {
           language : 'English'
}
```

So I am not able to give same name as `ng-model='peopleData.language'` in both select and textbox.

Since my backend developers do not want add an extra property in JSON. So I have to handle it in different way. I do not want to write any logic at the time of sending data to Service (create or manupulate JSON structure).

So is there any way to solve this problem?

**Note:** I know I can use `$scope.$watch` but still I am looking for better solution, such as completely handled from view it self, otherwise it could be a performance issue.

Comment: So use different models, no big deal.

Comment: Different model means different property on JSON structure. That is want I want to avoid. If I use different model except my JSON structure then I have to sync from controller with either `$watch` or at the time of backend call.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use two models but without changing JSON structure. However, you really *want* to adjust it, because existing one doesn't fit the purpose (looks like). I'm not sure about your setup, but I can imagine there is list of predefined languages (that can't be changed), and there is on called "Other". So as a user I want to select "Other" and have it persisted on backend, **and** I also want to save my choice for other language. So resume: you backender might be wrong and you should insist.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Because if any way I can manage it from view then also I think I will lose two way data binding. So after populating data from back end I need to parse and set to the the corresponding field which is not good in angular I believe.

Comment: It's not good because it's too complex for such a simple thing. The simplest solution is always the best, and in this case too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## **.:: Answer Upadated ::.**

---

How about writing a simple directive?

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.main" f-model="peopleData.language" ng-options="i as i for i in langs"></select>
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.extra" f-model="peopleData.language" ng-if="ctrl.main == 'Other'">
```

**JS:**

```
app.directive('fModel', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        fModel: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        var handler = function(val) {
          var newVal = angular.copy(val || scope.fModel || '');
          scope.$applyAsync(function() {
            scope.fModel = newVal;
          });
          return newVal;
        }

        ngModel.$parsers.push(handler);
        ngModel.$formatters.push(handler);
      },
    };
}]);
```

**Check it out live [IN THIS PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/RiM9BoSGOscUola6Msja?p=preview):**

Comment: This is nice one but the major problem is it is only working as own way binding. I have tried to set value at `$scope.peopleData.language = 'EN';` and it is not showing. I think we need to put some watch as well. Please suggest. Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/BjEFx9yT6IcQiMtcWQ09?p=preview

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh no need to do that, check the update.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I have another problem when value is other than existing list let say `$scope.peopleData.language = 'ABCD';` Then Other textfield is not opening. Moreover when I am selecting 'other' options then 'other' is also showing in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

i think can solve the issue by

in controller

```
$scope.languale = ['English', 'French', 'German' and 'Other'];
```

in view

```
<select ng-model="people.language" ng-options="lan in languale" ng-selected="lan==people.language"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change in text field...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="otherLang" ng-change="peopleData.language=otherLang">
```

As Text Field is only visible when there is **other** option selected so I think this will work.

http://embed.plnkr.co/pN04eXuDCCoR0Z8qhX4h/

Answer (score 0):

**View:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="peopleData.language" ng-options="item for item in languages"></select>
    
    <!-- Show input when selected language is Other -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-show="peopleData.language === 'Other'"/>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl',  
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.inputValue = '';
  
      // Languages list
      $scope.languages = ['English', 'French', 'German', 'Other'];
     
      // Selected language
      $scope.peopleData = {
        language : 'English'
      };
    }
  );
```

Demo: [Here!](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/MebMoN?editors=1010)

Note: Use `ng-show` will keep value of input when selected any language, it just hide, not remove from DOM. If you want to reset input value, use `ng-if` in this case.